# Android: Division always 0

Tags: android, android-activity

When I run my program my response is always 0 when I do the division below?  I have read one article on stack, but it seemed much more complicated and involved multiple variables and I couldn't see where it was the same.  If anyone can provide any assistance on what is wrong with my math in my if and else statements I would appreciate it very much.  Sorry I'm new and this is my first language :/.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int inchesPerFoot = 12;
    int feetPerYard = 3;
    int yardsPerMile = 1760;
    double unitsRequested;
    double totalUnits;
    String unitChoice;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText units = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumberOfUnits);
        final Spinner Conversion = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Units_Array);
        Button Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Result));
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                unitsRequested = Integer.parseInt(units.getText().toString());
                DecimalFormat number = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
                if (Conversion.equals(inchesPerFoot))
                        totalUnits = (inchesPerFoot / unitsRequested);
                else
                if (Conversion.equals(feetPerYard))
                        totalUnits = (feetPerYard / unitsRequested);
                else
                if (Conversion.equals(yardsPerMile))
                        totalUnits = (yardsPerMile / unitsRequested);
                unitChoice = Conversion.getSelectedItem().toString();
                result.setText("Total Units for " + unitChoice +" is "+ number.format(totalUnits));
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `Spinner` object with some `int` values, e.g:

```
if (Conversion.equals(inchesPerFoot))
```

This is a meaningless comparison, and will never be true, so none of your conditions are ever met for calculating `totalUnits` and so your answer is zero.

`Conversion` is of type `Spinner` and `inchesPerFoot` is an `int`. You need to either get the spinner position index and compare against that, like this:

```
int spinnerIndex = Conversion.getSelectedItemPosition();
if (spinnerIndex == 0)
    totalUnits = (inchesPerFoot / unitsRequested);
else
if (spinnerIndex == 1)
    totalUnits = (feetPerYard / unitsRequested);
else
if (spinnerIndex == 2)
    totalUnits = (yardsPerMile / unitsRequested);
```

(assuming that your spinner items are in that order), or else get the selected spinner item contents (assuming it's a string containing an integer number) and use that:

```
int spinnerValue = Integer.parseInt(Conversion.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Alternatively you could get the spinner item contents as a `String` and do `String` comparisons against the different conversion types:

```
String spinnerValue = Conversion.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: You were write here is the final solution that I used to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You were right here is the final solution that I used to get it working.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
final double inchesPerFoot = 12;
final double feetPerYard = 3;
final double yardsPerMile = 1760;
double unitsRequested;
double totalUnits;
String unitChoice;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText units = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumberOfUnits);
    final Spinner Conversion = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Units_Array);
    Button Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Result));
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            unitsRequested = Integer.parseInt(units.getText().toString());
            DecimalFormat number = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
            unitChoice = Conversion.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (unitChoice.equals("Inches to Feet"))
                totalUnits = (unitsRequested / inchesPerFoot);
            else
            if (unitChoice.equals("Feet to Yards"))
                    totalUnits = (unitsRequested / feetPerYard);
            else
            if (unitChoice.equals("Yards to Miles"))
                    totalUnits = (unitsRequested / yardsPerMile);

            result.setText("Total Units for " + unitChoice +" is "+ number.format(totalUnits));
        }
    });

}
```